# linking.addEventListener is not working for ios when application is in foreground

Tags: react-native, push-notification, linker, deep-linking

For ios, if the push notification is received when the application is in foreground, when user clicks on push notification, Linking.addEventListener is not getting executed.

The requirement is to move the user to a specific page once the push notification is clicked.

If the the application is not running or application is open but in background. In both this cases the Linking.addEventListener works as expected.

**Code from appdelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
{
  return [RCTLinkingManager application:application openURL:url
                      sourceApplication:sourceApplication annotation:annotation];
}

// Only if your app is using [Universal Links](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html).
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity:(NSUserActivity *)userActivity
 restorationHandler:(void (^)(NSArray * _Nullable))restorationHandler
{
  return [RCTLinkingManager application:application
                   continueUserActivity:userActivity
                     restorationHandler:restorationHandler];
}
```

**react-native code to handle deep linking**

```
if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
      Linking.getInitialURL().then(url => {
        const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
        let c = url.replace("abcdapp://abcd/", "")
        navigate(c)    
        });

    } else {
      Linking.addEventListener('url', this.handleOpenURL);
    }
    Linking.addEventListener('url', this.handleOpenURL);
```

Comment: Are you solve it?

Comment: Have you solved this issue, if yes, please help me, I am also facing this issue for IOS.